# MySql, need a query to retrieve multiple fields from tables in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in a MySql database:

```
**EmpInfo**

ID               Name                Address
--------------------------------------------------------
10001            Rocky Silva         11, satellite street


**EmpContact**  notion ( M for mobile number and L for Landline number)

ID               Phone               Type
--------------------------------------------------------
10001          909099925               M
10001          20222525                L
```

I want to create a view in such a way that it returns me following in a single row (not in  double rows after cartesian product):

```
10001        Rocky Silva       11, satellite street  909099925      20222525
```

Can any one help me with a query?  I have tried different joins but with no luck; I think I am missing something...

Comment: Did you want each of the phone nbrs in its own column (ala Mr. Bannister's solution) , or is it ok to have a single column w/ all the phone numbers concatenated together into one big string (which using GROUP_CONCAT will provide)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name address, GROUP_CONCAT(phone) as phones
FROM EmpInfo
JOIN EmpContact USING (id)
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select i.ID,
       i.Name,
       i.Address,
       cm.Phone as Mobile,
       cl.Phone as Landline
from EmpInfo i
left join EmpContact cm on i.ID = cm.ID and cm.Type = 'M'
left join EmpContact cl on i.ID = cl.ID and cl.Type = 'L'
```

Comment: Extend this to include a column for each possible Type and I think we have a winner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT e.*, MAX(IF(ec.Type = 'M', ec.Phone, NULL)) M, MAX(IF(ec.Type = 'L', ec.Phone, NULL)) L FROM EmpInfo e
  LEFT JOIN EmpContact ec
    ON e.ID = ec.ID
GROUP BY e.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use group_concat function for that

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.address, group_concat(c.phone)
from empInfo i, empContact c
where c.id = i.id
group by i.id,i.name,i.address
```

this will give you all the phones comma-separated in one column. If you want separate columns, do this

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.address,
GROUP_CONCAT(if (Type = 'M', phone, NULL)) AS 'Mobile', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if (Type = 'L', phone, NULL)) AS 'Landline', 
from empInfo i, empContact c
where c.id = i.id
group by i.id,i.name,i.address
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of elements to be combined, you could do something like the following (for 2):

```
SELECT EmpInfo.*, EC1.Phone, EC2.Phone from EmpInfo, EmpContact as EC1, EmpContact is EC2
WHERE EmpInfo.ID = EC1.ID and EmpInfo.ID = EC2.ID and EC1.Phone < EC2.Phone
```

This assumes that there are exactly 2 phones for each ID

Comment: There isn't any restrictions for number of phone numbers belong to one person , there could be 3 or 4 max